# What we need to do exactly to move to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, eu-spouses, uk-citizens

I’m non-EU, Egyptian, and my wife is British and we want move to the UK. We been officially married for 3 years and we moved to Malta 8 month ago. Now I have a resident card in Malta, valid for 5 years as a family permit of an EU citizen.  I was just wondering if I still need to apply for a family permit to the UK from Malta, or can I just go to England and apply for the resident card there?

Answer (score 2):

As the holder of an Article 10 card, you do not need an EEA family permit as long as you meet the criteria listed on [the UK's page on the topic](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).  So you can just go to England and apply for a residence card there.